# How to send large Video file over http in c++?

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I am trying to build a web server for videos and my client is a web-browser. I am using HTTP with header structure with content-Disposition: attachment

```
std::string make_header(std::string filename, int file_size)
{
    std::ostringstream header;
    header << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
    header << "Content-Type: " << get_contenttype(filename) << "\r\n";
    header << "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename =\"" << filename << "\"\r\n";
    header << "Connection: close\r\n";
    header << "Content-Length: " << file_size << "\r\n\r\n";
    return header.str();
}
```

I am able to send small files but as soon as large files are given the server takes lot of time. I am using the following method to copy the video file to a local variable.

```
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Is there any way to send file using HTTP without actually loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: This is not C and there is no such thing as C/C++

Comment: Would a system dependent solution work for you? Which operating system are you developing for? On Linux for example you may be able to use the sendfile function https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html

Comment: You can use webrtc to stream the data to browser

Comment: @Joni Thanks i will check that , I am developing it for Linux

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I heard about chunk encoding in http will it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, of course. In the end, HTTP goes over TCP, which goes over IPv4/v6. IP is a sequence of small packets, and TCP is even a bytestream protocol. The other side won't notice that you are still reading bytes from disk when you're sending the first bytes.

In practice, that means the client can't see or won't care how many calls to `send()` you made. One bug call or a thousand small calls are equivalent.

I wouldn't bother with `istreambuf_iterator`. I'd just use `fread`, but I'd still use a `std::vector<char>` for the buffer. Just read 1 MB chunks and send those. Your OS isn't going to choke on either an 1MB disk read or a 1MB send call.

For a higher-end solution I'd use Boost::asio on Windows, or [`sendfile`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) on Linux.